# Java: Check if NO key is pressed

Tags: java

How do I check if NO Key is pressed? I'm using a KeyListener to check if specific keys are pressed, but I cant figure out how to check all keys.

I imagine sth like this:

```
if (nokeyispressed == true) {
 dosomething();
}
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Just have a look at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html...

Comment: If no key is pressed, nothing happened, so you have to keep state of the pressed buttons in some sort of boolean in the interval you want to check no keys are pressed and at the end of the interval you will know if any key was pressed.